# Ajuste na tradução de notificação de medalha

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização, medalhas, notificações

Hoje ganhei uma medalha e achei estranha a mensagem de notificação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Devia ser:

> **Você ganhou a medalha `$Medalha$` por `$Pergunta$`**

mas está:

> Você ganhou a `$Medalha$` medalha por `$Pergunta$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alguém decidiu que, em algumas mas não todas, as mensagens de recebimento de medalha a tradução correta de:

> You've earned the "$Medalha$" badge (...)

seria

> Você ganhou a "$Medalha$" medalha (...)

Corrigi todos que vi. Vai pro ar no próximo build, o que pode demorar já que é noite de sexta feira e a gente tenta evitar fazer build bêbado.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/

Comment: Ahahahahah Gabe o que eu me ri agora :D

Comment: Está funcionando, alguém deve ter feito o commit sóbrio. Inclusive funciona retroativo, aquela mesma notificação agora eu vejo com o texto correto.